# how to show horizontal and vertical gradient divider line?

Tags: android, xml, layout, divider

[image]

I am little good at coding but when it comes to designing part in android, I always cannot make it out. gradient color works at vertical but not in horizontal. Can anyone suggest me how to get those divider on horizontal line to whole item like in vertical?

my divider.xml

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:endColor="@android:color/white"
    android:centerColor="#000"
    android:startColor="@android:color/white"
    android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

design.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:context="com.thebrogrammers.design.MainActivity"
   tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
   android:background="@color/grey">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Apply For Icard"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/divider2"/>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            >


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?
                    android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Apply For Icard"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/divider"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?
                    android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Apply For Icard"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/divider2"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?
                    android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Apply For Icard"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


      </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: with recyclerview ?. You use a custom grid item decoration  by extending  `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`

Comment: check this https://gist.github.com/raghunandankavi2010/5f78efb5c08e9c63d39b52bc6fe6494d

Comment: I never use gridview in past! :|

Comment: oh ok. just google and you should get a variety of item decorators if you use recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using line instead ? :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<item android:top="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:left="-5dp">
    <shape>
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width=".8dp"
            android:color="@color/black" />

    </shape>

</item>
```

the above divider for vertical one, and this for horizontal one :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <item android:top="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp" android:left="-5dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width=".8dp"
                android:color="@color/company_color" />

        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

try with your own width.

**OR** remove this line from your current divider `android:centerColor="#000"`

Comment: should i use this on my divider.xml ?

Comment: it don't give gradient line like i have in vertical !!

Comment: @Krixnaas you can add start color and end color if need. the same in your divider.

Comment: adding that color gives blank design

Comment: ok what about use your old divider and remove this line `android:centerColor="#000"`

Comment: great ! , happy to help : )

Answer (score 1):

we can achieve this using imageView by setting its background with gradient. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:centerColor="#000"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:angle="0"
            android:type="linear"/>
    </shape>
```

Then set the background of the imageView like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
```

Comment: Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Clever workaround!

Answer (score 0):

divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#00000000" android:startColor="#00000000" android:type="linear" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:top="@dimen/_20sdp" android:bottom="@dimen/_20sdp" android:left="@dimen/_2sdp" android:right="@dimen/_2sdp">
                <shape>
                    <gradient
                        android:angle="90"
                        android:startColor="#07FFFFFF"
                        android:centerColor="#D3000000"
                        android:endColor="#07FFFFFF"
                        android:type="linear" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

example.xml

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/divider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3.4"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).